# "GetDetailsOf" Method Returning Property Name, not the Value

Tags: vbscript

I am trying to find the "Author" and "Last Modified By" details of every file in a directory, and I am using VBScript to loop through since I think that that would be quicker than using VBA. The issue I am having is that my code returns just "Owner" and "Author" instead of the actual values. I don't have an issue getting these values in VBA, but it's painfully slow.

I have the following code so far :

```
Set objDlg = WScript.CreateObject("Shell.Application")
'''startFolder = objStartFolder.ParentFolder.ParseName(objStartFolder.Title).Path
startFolder = oShell.NameSpace("C:\Users\x4ujoh\Desktop\")

'Run the function 
ReportFiles startFolder

Function ReportFiles(folderName)
    Dim objFolder, objFile, fileCollection, folderCollection, subFolder

    Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(folderName)
    Set fileCollection = objFolder.Files

    For Each objFile In fileCollection
        strFilePath = Chr(34) & objFile.Path & Chr(34) 
        strFileName = Chr(34) & objFile.Name & Chr(34)
        strFileSize = objFile.Size / 1024
        strFileType = Chr(34) & objFile.Type & Chr(34)
        strFileDateCreated = objFile.DateCreated
        strFileDateLastAccessed = objFile.DateLastAccessed
        strFileDateLastModified = objFile.DateLastModified

        strFilePathRep = Replace(objFile.Path, objFile.Name, "")

        strFileAuthor = Chr(34) & objDlg.NameSpace(strFilePathRep).GetDetailsOf(objFile.Name, 10) & Chr(34)
        strFileLastModifiedBy = Chr(34) & objDlg.NameSpace(strFilePathRep).GetDetailsOf(objFile.Name, 20) & Chr(34)

        objReportFile.Write(strFilePath & "," & strFileName & "," & strFileSize & "," & strFileType & "," & strFileDateCreated & "," & strFileDateLastAccessed & "," & strFileDateLastModified & "," & strFileAuthor & "," & strFileLastModifiedBy & Chr(13) & Chr(10))
    Next

    'Loop for each sub folder 
    Set folderCollection = objFolder.SubFolders

    For Each subFolder In folderCollection
       ReportFiles subFolder.Path
    Next
End Function
```

[image]

Comment: Which code number in VBScript today represents the "Last Author"? 10 seems to be the "Owner" and 20 is the "Author" (originally), but looping from 1 - 300 doesn't seem to show anything similar to "Last Author"

Comment: There is no attribute called "Last Author".  not sure where you're setting that...

Comment: ...also just to confirm, you need VBScript; you're not doing this through Excel, etc?   I am going to improve upon my answer [here on AWF](https://access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showpost.php?p=1536903&postcount=3) (since looking back, I can see a couple inefficiencies, plus I need an improved version for myself) but it's going to be at least partly Excel based.

Comment: re: `Last Author`... Are the files you're interested in *MS Office* documents?  Is the field possibly actually called `Last Modified By`?  Depending on how you answer that, there's possibly 1 of 2 ways you can retrieve that information.

Comment: What I have seen so far is that one way to access the item is using "Last Saved By" = [Object].BuiltinDocumentProperties("Last Author") but I have only seen this with regards to MS Office objects / using VBA. I would need a confirmation that this audit information is exclusive to MS Office. If that is the case, then I will limit the property gathering to these MS-specific objects.

Comment: I've been working on extracting metadata from various filetypes not accessible with `GetDetailsOf`, and I'm had interesting success with [exiftool](https://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/) command line [EXIF data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exif) reader/writer.  Technically it's intended to store metadata for photos (ie., camera model, geotags, etc) but it seems to store most, if not all Office documents properties as well including `Last Modified By`, and even user-generated custom document properties.

Comment: Ran into this thread and discovered a potential cause for this issue, which turns out to be handy.  If a non-valid file object is given to  GetDetailsOf() then the function will return the NAME of the property rather than its VALUE (since there is no property because the object is not valid).  So instead of GetDetailsOf(...,2) returning "Adobe Acrobat Document" it will return "Item Type".  This comes in handy for figuring out what number to use for GetDetailsOf, since the meaning of the numbers is not documented.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `GetDetailsOf(objFile, ...)` instead of `GetDetailsOf(objFile.Name, ...)`

Comment: Any idea why this is? It's rather odd behavior that appears undocumented.

Comment: @ClaySweetser According to the documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/folder-getdetailsof, `GetDetailsOf` takes `FolderItem` parameter rather than `string`, so it is indeed documented :)